# How to properly pass pageId prop to Navbar in Reactjs using Nextjs 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am building a website for the first time using React, Nextjs 13, and Tailwindcss but I am having an issue passing down the pageId prop from my RootLayout to my Navbar function.

```
import '../app/globals.css';

type NavbarProps = {
    pageId: string
}

function Navbar(props: NavbarProps) {
    const { pageId } = props
    return (
        <>
            <div className="absolute left-0 top-0 w-full z-10"> {/* flex justify-center flex-wrap mx-auto pt-6 w-full*/}
                <nav className={`max-w-full m-auto flex justify-between items-center ${pageId == "home" ? "text-white" : "text-black"} p-4 z-[2]`}> {/*inline-flex items-center rounded-lg flex-warp bg-green-100 p-3*/}
                    <a href="/"
                        className="font-bold text-4xl"><b>Test Site</b> {/*inline-flex rounded-lg items-center p-2 mr-4 bg-cyan-100 text-bold*/}
                        <span className="text-xl text-black font-bold uppercase tracking-wide"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul className="hidden sm:flex z-[2]"> {/*inline-flex rounded-lg bg-white/90 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-zinc-800 shadow-lg shadow-zinc-800/5 ring-1 ring-zinc-900/5 backdrop-blur*/}
                        <NavItem title={"Page 1"} url={"/Page-1"} isSelected={props.pageId == "page-1"} />
                        <NavItem title={"Page 1"} url={"/Page-2"} isSelected={props.pageId == "page-2"} />
                        <NavItem title={"About Page"} url={"/About"} isSelected={props.pageId == "about"} />
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

type NavItemProps = {
    title: string
    url: string
    isSelected: boolean
}

function NavItem(props: NavItemProps) {
    const { title, url, isSelected } = props
    return (
        <li>
            <a className={`block px-3 py-2 transition hover:text-cyan-500 ${isSelected ? "text-cyan-500" : ""}`} href={url}>{title}</a>
        </li>
    )
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: any) {
    console.log(children.props.pageId)
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar pageId={children.props.pageId} />
            <main>{children}</main>
        </>
    )
}
```

I was following a textbook to learn how to code the website and everything is working fine apart from this issue as I am getting this error:

```
- error app\layout.tsx (39:31) @ pageId
- error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pageId')
    at RootLayout (./app/layout.tsx(101:32)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)

       export default function RootLayout({ children }: any) {
>          console.log(children.props.pageId)
                                     ^
```

I tried looking up online to see if anyone has had a similar issue in nextjs 13 and if there were any suggestions in the book or on the authur's github page but I couldn't find anything that I found helpful. If anyone can help that would be great as I am confused of how to fix this issue or why exactly it is happening.